# Is it possible to set the focus on a vaadin-grid record programmatically?

Tags: typescript, accessibility, vaadin-grid, hilla

The use case is that I need to delete a record from a vaadin-grid using a confirmation dialog and then return focus inside the grid, to the previous/next record of the deleted one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually referring to selected item as you are not talking about focusing a cell. If so there is `selectedItems` property in the `vaadin-grid`, which you can set. As you are using Hilla, you probably need to have state variable for that, update the state, which will trigger re-render of the view using the value. It is an array, as `vaadin-grid` has both multiselection and single selection modes.

```
@state()
private selectedItems: Person[] = [];

render() {
  return html`
    <vaadin-grid
      .items="${this.items}"
      .selectedItems="${this.selectedItems}"
      }}"
    >
      <vaadin-grid-column path="firstName"></vaadin-grid-column>
      <vaadin-grid-column path="lastName"></vaadin-grid-column>
      <vaadin-grid-column path="email"></vaadin-grid-column>
    </vaadin-grid>
  `;
}
```